# Read Excel file and return the names of people that scored zero for a specific time range

Tags: matlab

I need to read an Excel file with a table like this:

```
Name   | Time   | Score
------ | ------ | ------
Bill   | 11:15  | 2.4
Bill   | 13:00  | 0
Bill   | 20:00  | 0
Steve  | 6:00   | 4.7
Steve  | 13:45  | 0
Steve  | 17:45  | 3
Jack   | 9:00   | 0
Jack   | 13:30  | 7.2
Jack   | 19:30  | 0
```

And return the names of people whose score was 0 between 13:00 and 14:00. The correct answer in this example would be:

```
Name   | 
------ | 
Bill   |
Steve  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use additional outputs from [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) to get all the text and numeric data:

```
[score, textData] = xlsread('temp.xlsx');
```

Next, you'll want to convert the second column of text (your time data) to a format that will be easier to do comparisons on, like a [serial date number](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```
timeData = datenum(textData(2:end, 2));
```

Now you can create [logical indices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) showing which rows have a score of 0 and a time within the given range:

```
index = (score == 0) & (timeData >= datenum('13:00')) & (timeData <= datenum('14:00'));
```

And finally you can use this index to select the corresponding names (using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to remove any repeated names):

```
nameData = textData(2:end, 1);
unique(nameData(index))

ans =

  2×1 cell array

    'Bill'
    'Steve'
```